# Convert 2D array to single array

Tags: c, arrays

suppose i have a two D array.

```
#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 3

char a[ROWS][COLS]= {
                        {'1','2','3'},
                        {'4','5','6'},
                        {'7','8','9'}
                      };
```

How can I copy values of that to a single array. I want only COLS values.

Comment: what do you mean by you only want COLS values? Do you mean you want to do a column-wise vectorization?

Answer (score 1):

1) If you need to copy the array in row wise order
you could use :

-first have a 1D array that could hold all the elements of 2D array, then use
    memcpy(new1Darr, org2Darr, total size in bytes);

like for above example,
    memcpy(new1Darray, a, sizeof(char)*ROWS*COLS)

2) Instead of (1) or if you want to change the order in which the data must be stored then just traverse through the 2D array the way you want(column major) and copy the elements one by one. Like (considering you define all the variables first)

This will copy the elements in the new array in column wise order

```
k=0;
for(j=0;j<COLS;j++)
{
    for(i=0;i<ROWS;i++)
    {
        new1Darray[k] = a[i][j];
        k++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple. Lets see 'how?'-

```
    #define ROWS 3
    #define COLS 3

    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>

    char a[ROWS*COLS]={'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

    void main()
    {
     for(int i=0; i<ROWS*COLS;i=i+COLS)
     {
      for(int j=0; j<COLS; j++)
      {
       printf("%c\t",a[i+j]); //access array
      }
      printf("\n");
     }
     getch();
    }
```