# Attempting to convert a 2 dimensional array to single dimension in embedded C

Tags: c, arrays

As I have found it very difficult to manipulate 2 dimensional arrays in C, I've decided to try and write a function that will take my 2D array and convert it to a 1D array. For the 2D array below I'd like it to translate to some thing like `1D_array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 }`.

I came across a very similar question on stack exchange, linked below, and have used the suggested code.

[Convert 2D array to single array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800896/convert-2d-array-to-single-array)

The code I'm using is:

```
#define KP_ROWS 4
#define KP_COLS 4

static Uint16 KP_TEST_Keys[KP_ROWS][KP_COLS] = {
    {  1,  2,  3,  4 },
    {  5,  6,  7,  8 },
    {  9, 10, 11, 12 },
    { 13, 14, 15, 16 }
};

void main()
{
    Uint16 array1D[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    memcpy(array1D, KP_TEST_Keys, sizeof(Uint16) * KP_ROWS * KP_COLS);
}
```

Again my overall goal is to convert the 2D array to a 1D array.

EDIT: After clearing errors from before I have edited and just now tested the above code and it works! `array1D` contains the data in the format I wanted.

Comment: Is this a full code of programm? If yes, then it shouldn't work, becouse you can usem memcpy only in function body, not in global scope.

The second thing is u can simply write `Uint16 array1D[16];`. 

Give a full program code with a main func.

Comment: I think you could just do `Uint16 *array1D = (Uint16 *)&KP_TEST_Keys;` without doing `memcpy()`

Comment: @technosaurus  Any particular reason for `&` in `(Uint16 *)&KP_TEST_Keys`?

Comment: @chux - just being explicit, its not necessary.

Comment: Note `void main()` in  a non-standard form.  Suggest `int main(void)`

Comment: You should probably ask a question about your problems with 2D arrays rather than this nonsense lest you simply perpetuate some fundamental misunderstanding of the language.

Comment: @technosaurus :  *explicit* perhaps, but unusual and potentially confusing.  If `KP_TEST_Keys` were a pointer to the data rather than a static array (as it could become under maintenance for example), then `&KP_TEST_Keys` would be semantically different (and incorrect), so it is in fact *safer* not to do that.

Comment: Side note: you may as well declare `Uint16 array1D[sizeof(KP_TEST_Keys)/sizeof(Uint16)]`, and then call `memcpy(array1D, KP_TEST_Keys, sizeof(KP_TEST_Keys))`.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I using memcpy correctly?

OK, but prone to failure as  the size of `array1D` is not certainly tied to the size of `KP_TEST_Keys`.

```
Uint16 array1D[KP_ROWS*KP_COLS] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} ;

// Recommend size of destination, not size of source
// Ideally, it would be the minimum of the size of source and destination.
memcpy(array1D, KP_TEST_Keys, sizeof array1D);
```

As [@Kurokawa Masato](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963718/attempting-to-convert-a-2-dimensional-array-to-single-dimension-in-embedded-c#comment59582506_35963718) commented,  `memcpy()` must be used in a function.

---

Suggest using standard types like `uint16_t` rather than `Uint16`.

Comment: Modified the code as you suggested: `uint16_t array1D[16] = {0}; memcpy(array1D,KP_TEST_Keys,sizeof(array1D));` 

When I initialize the 1D array as `uint16_t array1D[KP_ROWS*KP_COLS] = {0};` the compiler spits an error. But when I initialize the array as `uint16_t array1D[16] = {0};` the code compiles fine and works as desired. Why would the compiler not like the initialization with two constants multiplied in the index?

Comment: @JeremiahOgletree "the compiler spits an error."  --> What was the text of the error message - that helps a lot.  Possible `KP_ROWS,KP_COLS` was not in "scope"?

Comment: It says: variable "array1D" may.
I'm using Texas Instruments Code Composer Studio as an IDE. It seems like the error message gets cut off for some reason and doesn't complete what it's meant to convey.

Comment: @JeremiahOgletree Perhaps it is about the initialization - which is not needed.  IAC, sounds like your compiler needs to go to compiler school.

Comment: Got rid of the init and it works with the index as KP_ROWS*KP_COLS. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The 2D array data is already stored contiguously in the order you require of your 1D array; there is no need at all to duplicate the data in a separate array; you only need cast the 2D array as follows:

```
Uint16* array1D = (Uint16*)KP_TEST_Keys ;
```

This provides a 1D array *view* of the 2D array without copying the data.  Changes to the 1D view change the 2D data directly so there is no need to copy to and from the two representations.

If the 1D array view is to be read-only you can enforce that by:

```
const Uint16* array1D = (const Uint16*)KP_TEST_Keys ;
```

Further if the 1D array is to be locked to the 2D array and not to be capable of reassignment to some other array then:

```
Uint16* const array1D = (Uint16* const)KP_TEST_Keys ;
```

or both combined ( a constant pointer to constant data):

```
const Uint16* const array1D = (const Uint16* const)KP_TEST_Keys ;
```

One significant difference here is that `sizeof(array1D)` is the size of the pointer, not the size of the array; you should use `sizeof(KP_TEST_Keys)` for both.

If either if these declarations is made at file scope after the declaration of `KP_TEST_Keys`, the 1D view will exist with the same *lifetime* and *scope* as the 2D:

```
static Uint16 KP_TEST_Keys[KP_ROWS][KP_COLS] = {
    {  1,  2,  3,  4 },
    {  5,  6,  7,  8 },
    {  9, 10, 11, 12 },
    { 13, 14, 15, 16 }
};
static Uint16* array1D = (Uint16*)KP_TEST_Keys ;
```

You can also perform the cast directly at point of use rather then introducing a new variable to access individual elements such as:

```
Uint16 element = ((Uint16*)KP_TEST_Keys)[i] ;
```

where `i` is the 1D index 0 to `sizeof(KP_TEST_Keys) - 1`.

Comment: My own answer notwithstanding, the OP should really address his deficiency of understanding of 2D arrays and ask a question about resolving that rather then implementing his somewhat perverse avoidance of them.  This is a classic XY question - *"I have a problem X, I invented a solution Y, how do I do Y?"*  Just ask about X!